# Investigating slow windows boot (in safe mode)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

My Windows 8.1 demonstrates slow load recently, and quite unclear behaviour during boot.
I started with `xbootmgr` logging, and it appears that almost 5-6 mins of the initial boot is just `System.exe` doing something with these files:

```
C:\$LogFile
Unknown, Flush

C:\$BitMap
C:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog
C:\$Extend\$UsnJrnl:$J
C:\$Mft

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup\EtwRTEventLog-System.etl

\Device\HarddiskVolume1
\Device\HarddiskVolume1\$LogFile
\Device\HarddiskVolume1\$Mft
```

Log Screenshot: [image: etl view]

It's definitely not logging itself; `C:\Temp\boot_BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+FI` is the first file on-screen and is probably not antivirus since booting in Safe Mode has the same long delay.

What's going on and how to investigate it further?

Comment: If you're using a mechanical HDD, use [`contig`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/contig) (or it's GUI `PowerDefragmenter`) to defragment the hidden files the drive's firmware and filesystem use for file access (`$Boot`, `$Logfile`, `$MFT`, etc.).  That should help, but if not, boot to WinRE and delete the three system files used by the OS ( `C:\hiberfil.sys`, `C:\pagefile.sys`, `C:\swapfile.sys`), as well as the user's temp directory (`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`) empty the RecycleBin, then reboot.

Comment: If it is a HDD I would strongly recommend to check the SMART values of the disk before performing any defragmentation. If the HDD is end-of-life defrag is good way to finish it totally.

Comment: @JW0914 thanks, very much possible that your ideas have worked, though it is SSD disk. I'm not sure how it must be dealt with in terms of stack answer, but feel free to copy my answer below - I'll mark it as answer to give you credits.

Comment: @AnnoNymous Thanks, but that's your answer, so mark it as accepted so you get the rep for it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

in offline mode:

- check disk with standard window GUI (with error correction, which found no errors)
- defragment disk with standard window GUI
- defragment NTFS files with [contig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/contig)
- delete hiberfil, pagefile, swapfile, clean Temp folders

additionally, in online mode

- check system with "sfc /scannow"

Load time is perfect now.
Reason of this not being fixed by system automatically is unclear though.

Solution is mostly proposed by [JW0914](https://superuser.com/users/529800/jw0914), should be turned into community knowledge soon

Comment: A few FYIs: Windows defrag doesn't defrag SSDs, it TRIMs them.  It's not recommended to utilize normal defrag on SSDs due to the numerous writes to disk, which is why it's only recommended to use defrag apps that support TRIM for an SSD.  The only files I personally would do an actual defrag on would be the specific firmware/filesystem special directories (`$MFT`, `$Logfile`, etc.).  When running `SFC`, the following should be issued in the order listed: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot.